# CSS "underline" text part

Tags: jquery, css

How can I "underline" text to get the same effect like you can see under "TEST"?

[image: The blue "rectangle under TEST"]

I tried to encapsulate TEST in a `span` and adding an absolute :after with `position: absolute`, but I think it's not the correct way and haven't been able to obtain the expected result.

Here's the HTML

```html
<h1 class="white hero-text">
    <span class="thin">ALL THIS TEXT IS</span>
    <br>
    <span class="bold striked">A TEST</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: can you not just use text-decoration:underline on your span?

Comment: @frnt i just added the HTML code - The css part is not yet done obv

Comment: Random stab in the dark here, step back please, I will not accept responsibility for any injuries: declare `position: relative` on the `span` element in question, then declare the following on the `pseudo-element`: `span:after { left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; bakground: blue; height: 30px; /* adjust accordningly */ }` *Edit:* Oh look, a Code Snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body{
  background: #333;
  font-family: arial;
}

.hero-text{
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.bold.striked{
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bold.striked::before{
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #4882d5;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="white hero-text">
    <span class="thin">ALL THIS TEXT IS</span>
    <br>
    <span class="bold striked">A TEST</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You said you tried with `:after` . That's the right solution. See snippet below.
You can change the values

```css
.striked {
  position: relative
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.striked:after {
  height: 50%;
  width: 150%;
  left: -25%;
  background: red;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<h1 class="white hero-text">
    <span class="thin">ALL THIS TEXT IS</span>
    <br>
    <span class="bold striked">A TEST</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: It's a good idea but on the main container I've a background-image so the .striked:after is going under that image

Comment: @GiacomoTorricelli well...please share all relevant info. Otherwise i can only guess a solution for you. play around with the z-index

Answer (score 1):

Use pseudo selector `:before` as you mentioned and add `span tag` to only that section where you want that `border` bottom styling as in above image.

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
span:before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:10px;
  background:yellow;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:3px;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="white hero-text">
    ALL THIS TEXT IS
    <br>
    <span>A TEST</span>
</h1>
```