# Add a single border only for a part of the text

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS and I am trying to add a border only for the text under the main headline. 
Here is a code snippet with my existing code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #00394d;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff668c;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>Simple contact form</h1>
    
        <h2>First name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="100">
        <h2>Last name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"  size="30" maxlength="100">
        <h2>Email</h2>
        <input type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100">
        <h2>Phone number</h2>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" size="30" maxlength="100">
        <h2>City</h2>
        <input type="text" name="city" size="30" maxlegth="100">
        <h2>Message</h2>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="comments"></textarea><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        
    </div>
    </body>
```

My final result should look like this image [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNo3.png).

Comment: _"text under the main headline"_ meaning the `h1`? Also, your image doesn't show any underlined text as far as I can tell. Also, what did you try to achieve it, if anything?

Comment: Can you share what css you have tried? Which is the text under the main headline?  It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yea h1 is the main headline.

Comment: adding borders etc are related to css so we need to see your css code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332549/css-underline-text-part

Comment: the current css code is: body {
      background-color: #00394d;
}

 
   h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    
}
     h2 {
     font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 16px;
    color:  #ff668c;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    
}

       </style>

Comment: by 'text under the main headline', you mean the text in <h1> or the text in <h2>

Comment: i want to make one border(like a window) only for the text after h1(from first name to  the input "submit")

Comment: For future reference, don't add code in comments, edit your question to contain the relevant code - and make it a stack snippet, so we can run the code right from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So (according to your comments and image) you mean you want to put everything into a box under the main header. Well, you have to wrap that part into a `div` and use (approximately) the following CSS for that box and the input elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: #00394d;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff668c;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 340px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

input,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <h1>Simple contact form</h1>
  <div class="box1">
    <h2>First name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" maxlength="100">
    <h2>Last name</h2>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" maxlength="100">
    <h2>Email</h2>
    <input type="email" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100">
    <h2>Phone number</h2>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" size="30" maxlength="100">
    <h2>City</h2>
    <input type="text" name="city" size="30" maxlegth="100">
    <h2>Message</h2>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="comments"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question **(add a border only for the text under the main headline)** you want some thing like `100px` `border` for `h1` tag. [Example is here](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/xxbLypy).

[image]

**CSS**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #00394d;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.page{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto 25px;
  padding: 10px 0 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

h1:after{
  background-color: #ff668c;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
```

You no need to set `display` property for `h1`. Add some **CSS** for `.page` how child element will be. Use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). `.page{align-items: center;display: flex;flex-direction: column;}`.

> Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to explain so I made a snippet. Long story short, use `display: inline-block;`

```css
h1 { 
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-color: white;
}
div {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
  hi stinky pinky (underline text only)
  </h1>
  <h2>
   How dare u call me stinky (full width underline)
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap heading inside a div and add display: inline-block to it.

```
h1 {
 ...
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a demo of it [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j7wn90Lk/)